# Is an emergency blanket effective as a ground sheet?

Tags: gear, hiking, wild-camping, ultralight

On a recent [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/what-is-a-realistic-weight-for-a-week-long-hike/13088#13088) that was closed as a duplicate (correctly) one of the comments was to use a foil blanket as a ground sheet instead of a tarpaulin in a bid to reduce the overall pack weight. Is this an effective strategy? I have images of the foil tearing after being lain on and stretched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use an emergency blanket as a substitute for most of a tarp's uses, but as you suspect it's not going to be as durable.

The Mylar that they're made of is surprisingly tough and I doubt that it would rip or tear, but I would expect it to develop plenty of very small punctures and begin to lose its aluminum coating (possibly making a glittery mess) within a few uses.  It would be worth picking a brand and testing them out before committing to it.

Personally I like to carry a contractor's trash bag.  I hammock and use the trash bag to store my pack and boots to keep them dry while I sleep or as a pack-liner.  The bag can be cut open into a large makeshift tarp or poncho, they're tough.  They also begin to get small perforations and tears after a number of uses, but I'd suspect they'd be stronger than Mylar–although they're also heavier.

Answer (score 7):

You can in a pinch, but not what it is made for.  Won't last very long at all and will make a ton of noise.  Get a piece of [Tyvek](http://www.backpacker.com/view/photos/gear-photos/make-a-tyvek-groundcloth-for-your-tent/#bp=0/img1) and cut it to size. Cheap, light and durable.  Can't beat it.

Comment: Tyvek is amazing!  Some of my White Mountain maps are Tyvek and until I got them I never realized how bomber the stuff is.